# Django 1.10 converting question marks to percent signs in static file urls

Tags: python, django

I am upgrading Django from 1.7 to 1.10 in my project.

All static files are loaded correctly. However, the ones with versions(or any other param) are not. The reason is that Django is converting question marks to `%` for some reason.

Example:

```
<script src="{% static 'dashboard/js/dashboard.js?v=1.11.0' %}"></script>
```

is converted to

```
/static/dashboard/js/dashboard.js%3Fv%3D1.11.0
```

Static files configuration:

```
STATIC_URL = '/static/'
STATICFILES_STORAGE = 'django.contrib.staticfiles.storage.StaticFilesStorage'
DEFAULT_FILE_STORAGE = 'django.core.files.storage.FileSystemStorage'
STATICFILES_FINDERS = (
    'django.contrib.staticfiles.finders.FileSystemFinder',
    'django.contrib.staticfiles.finders.AppDirectoriesFinder',
)
```

What could be the reason?

Comment: It's escaping it as it it'd conflict with a genuine qmark being used as the start of a query string. You could try "{% static 'dashboard/js/dashboard.js' %}?v=1.11.0" and see if that works...

Comment: have you tried to use `autoescape` ? https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.10/ref/templates/builtins/#autoescape

Comment: @JonClements thanks you very much for the idea. I moved `?v=1.11.0` part after a closing `%}` to have `%}?v=1.11.0` and it is apparently working. I wonder what changed between django1.7 and django1.10. Anyways, if you post it as an answer, I will accept it. Thank you!

Comment: The change occurred recently, ticket related to it at https://code.djangoproject.com/ticket/25484

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The `{% static path %}` template tag expects `path` to be a valid file path and escapes it. Use the following syntax instead:

```
 <script src="{% static 'dashboard/js/dashboard.js' %}?v=1.11.0"></script>
```